# Can GitHub Actions self hosted runners be used without a sandbox?

Tags: github, azure-devops, github-actions

Currently, we use Azure DevOps for build and release pipelines but host repos on GitHub. We would like to make use of GitHub actions to replace this and bring everything into one location.

We use a self hosted Azure DevOps release pipeline which allows us to download and configure our app on our own server.

However the article [here](https://help.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners) implies that GitHub Actions self hosted runners utilise a sandbox.

Could they be used without a sandbox to copy our program to a path on our server and then run the program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing in that article that implies anything about self-hosted runners being sandboxed from an internal network perspective.

> Self-hosted runners offer more control of hardware, operating system,
>   and software tools than GitHub-hosted runners provide. With
>   self-hosted runners, you can choose to create a custom hardware
>   configuration with more processing power or memory to run larger jobs,
>   **install software available on your local network**, and choose an
>   operating system not offered by GitHub-hosted runners. **Self-hosted
>   runners can be physical, virtual, container, on-premises, or in a
>   cloud**.

Comment: The article only mentions in passing. It warns that, if you add to a public repo, code might bypass "the machine's runner sandbox".

Comment: The main limit on the runner seems to be its use of the `nt authority\network service` account. Please see my new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61048334/how-to-add-privileges-to-the-nt-authority-network-service-account-for-github-act) on how I can add the desired privileges to this account.

Comment: Noting that, as @Lex Li commented on my answer, GitHub Actions doesn't actually use a sandboxing technology. The account it runs under is also configurable to give it desired permissions.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub Actions runs under the `nt authority\network service` account.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account:

> It has minimum privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network.

Therefore the "machine's runner sandbox" referred to in the article is likely referencing this account's inability to perform any privileged tasks.

Comment: Nope. I don't think so. "Sandbox" in that GitHub article is more of a metaphor than any specific sandboxing technology. Besides, when you configure a custom action runner, you can choose another account (in most cases you won't use Network Service).