# How to add privileges to the nt authority\network service account for GitHub Actions?

Tags: windows, windows-server, github-actions

GitHub Actions self-hosted runners run under the `nt authority\network service` account.

According to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/networkservice-account:

> It has minimum privileges on the local computer and acts as the computer on the network.

I am trying to use a GitHub Actions self-hosted runner to deploy an app to my server. To do this I need to access `schtasks.exe` which currently gives `ERROR: Access is denied.`

How can I give privileges to `nt authority\network service` so that it is able to access `schtasks.exe`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the easiest solution for my issue was to change the account the GitHub Actions service ran under.

I achieved this by using `powershell "(Get-Service actions.runner.*).name"`to find the name of the GitHub Actions service.

And then running `sc config "NAME_OF_YOUR_SERVICE" obj= "NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM" type= own` to update it to run as the system.

**EDIT:**

As @Lex Li says

> A CI agent (for Azure Pipelines or GitHub Actions) should run under a
>   dedicated account (on Windows usually a service account from Active
>   Directory), so that you can tune its permissions on various resources.

Comment: config.cmd does ask if you want to run the service under another account, so you rarely need to change that afterward (but you can, of course). BTW, the "very bad" part isn't that obvious. For a repo on GitHub with Actions enabled, it should be the responsibilities of the repo admin to set up everything properly, then other contributors simply use it (just like using a GitHub maintained runner). Those contributors should not expect access to the custom runner server.

Comment: My bad, I didn't notice that when setting up. I suppose the best way to handle the security would be a user account set up with the specific permissions needed. I was used to using Azure DevOps where the agent ran as system by default.

Comment: Correct. A CI agent (for Azure Pipelines or GitHub Actions) should run under a dedicated account (on Windows usually a service account from Active Directory), so that you can tune its permissions on various resources.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include this to remove any confusion for others who are not familiar with this.